# How do you stop an app that is running like an endless loop. With a button in WPF?

Tags: c#

I Have an App that is runnin like an endless loop.

I want that the App will stop running if i will press the 'Stop Runnin' Button.

In Consol it wiil be with the trigger Console.KeyAvailable (i want somthing like that).

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
    <Button Name="btnStart" Content="Run" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="46" Margin="186,248,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109" Click="btnStart_Click"/>
    <TextBlock Name="OutputText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="312,31,0,0" Height="204" Width="169" RenderTransformOrigin="0.495,0.511" />
    <Button Content="Stop Running" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="46" Margin="326,248,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="108" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            APPexample Example = new APPexample();
            Example.Run();
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Example.StopRunning = true;   
        App.Current.Shutdown();      
    }
}
```

Comment: So how does your current code not accomplish this?

Comment: Well, for starters, you can't access `Example` from `Button_Click` because it doesn't exist there.  `Example` will need to be a class-level variable.  I'm quite sure the compiler is telling you this in an error message which you aren't sharing for some reason.  (As well as the syntax error of your mis-matched curly braces.)

Comment: @APerson The app is tunning and the form is freezed. i can't press any button.

Comment: @AnnaBokovskaya: Whatever `APPexample` is (which we can't see), it would need to run its process on a separate thread.  If the process is blocking the main (UI) thread then the application won't be able to accept input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your start button is blocking the UI thread when it is running hence why you cannot click anything. Try the code below. Although without knowing what `APPexample` is I cannot say whether it will work or not

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                APPexample Example = new APPexample();
                Example.Run();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Example.StopRunning = true;   
        App.Current.Shutdown();      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

running APPexample in the way that you are running it, will most surely run on the UI thread, as you are suing WPF, that is the reason your application is locking up.

I would rather use a background thread to run it, and then in your start method, start the background worker and then in your stop method, ask it to stop.